# What are some big sites that are using Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm looking for examples of large websites that are hosted on Amazon EC2/S3/Cloudfront/etc.

I worked at a company where we ran a site that did 500k unique visitors per month on EC2 running 10 instances but that's still relatively small potatoes compared to some larger sites. I know smug mug and foursquare are also hosted on EC2. What other large websites are on EC2?

Comment: 500k uniques per month is only about 15k per day. Why did you need 10 instances?

Comment: Craig, we had 1 load balancer, 3 app servers, 1 MySQL master, 1 slave and then our dev, integration, qa, and continuous integration servers. The site also did some API traffic (around 200 request per minute) which isn't counted in the uniques.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reddit uses EC2

Answer (score 10):

How large is 'large'? I know that [heroku](http://heroku.com) runs on EC2, and they do a pretty large amount of traffic.

Comment: Good point, Heroku is a good example of a big company that does all its hosting on EC2

Answer (score 4):

Netflix, DropBox, Zynga (maker of Farmville) are pretty big users of EC2

Comment: netflix only for non-video content, dropbox moved to their own hardware.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Zynga has returned to AWS so it's once again using EC2.

Answer (score 2):

Instagram uses Amazon... at least their images are hosted on S3. Check out this link:

http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/09/17/42923def0eb141fc8bb4ab0c963d0dbc_6.jpg

Also, I'm pretty sure Reddit moved away from Amazon Cloud after the most recent outage.

Here's a link to Amazon case studies that details some of their larger clients:

http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/

Answer (score 0):

In the financial world Nasdaq OMX is a good example but virtually every bank uses EC2 for computational needs (not as a main system but highly used by both banks and hedge funds to run simulations).