# What are some big sites that are using Linode?

Tags: hosting, cloud, web-hosting, cloud-hosting, linode

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572086/what-are-some-big-sites-that-are-using-amazon-ec2); I'm looking for examples of large websites that are hosted on [Linode](http://www.linode.com/).

Comment: What do you consider 'large'?

Comment: `@Eaglebird:` It's tough, maybe impossible, to precisely define the kinds of websites understood to be "large". But I think we all know it when we see it.

Comment: @Rudiger: Have to disagree with you, "large" is so vague and subjective, it makes this question border on violation of the community standards.

Comment: Interesting question - I've never heard of the ones mentioned so far though!

Comment: @gview: Flagged as "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 2):

Mindvalley and Railscasts used to be hosted by Linode but moved to Slicehost.

Conan O'Brien's site teamcoco is hosted by linode, it has about 200K unique visitors (5-40 times more than the above mentioned sites), its Alexa rank is ~15,000

Mibbit is hosted by linode too, with 100K unique visitors.

Other notable sites include ModRails.com and Thoughtcrime.org

Comment: Are those figures uniques a day?

Answer (score 0):

[Mibbit](http://www.mibbit.com/).

Last I've heard (some months ago) they were using two (now probably more) *Linode 1024*.

Comment: Two virtual servers with 1GB memory? that's very small. - He's asking about big sites!

Comment: Depends on the definition of "big sites". Mibbit is a well known website with lots of visits, so I consider it a "big site".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mindvalley.com/

Last I heard (maybe a few weeks ago?) they from 20 up to 60 1.5gb linodes (they scale up or down depending on traffic load)

Comment: That's just a marketing website. I can't imagine that requires 60 servers unless they are not caching anything! Or is there something else they are hosting?